# Pointer to a Function in a Struct

Tags: c, struct

I have the following struct:

```
struct A {
   struct list * (* get_items) (void);
   char * (*build) (void);
}
```

Now the way `build` is assigned (which is a pointer to a function) is as follows:

```
struct A someVar = {
  .build = someBuildingFunction
};
```

I am not sure about the syntax for how `build` is assigned. Why is it starting with a dot? And furthermore, how would I point `get_items` to the appropriate function in `struct A someVar`? I've tried several ways and I keep getting errors.

I also noticed the lack of semicolon at the end of `somebuildingFunction`. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is it starting with a dot?

It's called a designated initializer.

> how would I point get_items to the appropriate function in struct A
>   someVar?

```
struct A someVar = {
  .build = someBuildingFunction,
  .get_items = someGettingFunction
};
```

You could omit the names of the members and just make sure you put the function names in the  right order.

> I also noticed the lack of semicolon at the end of
>   somebuildingFunction. Why is that?

That's common for initializers in C. For example:

```
int x[] = {
    1 /* No semicolon after 1. */
};
```